# How do I combine and conditions?

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm new to this site and programming so I'm sorry if this question is dumb.
I'll get to the point.

```
If (a == 1 && b == 2)
{
    executeFunction
}
If (a == 2 && b == 3)
{
    executeSameFunctionAsAbove
}
```

How would I combine the two if statements? Both will execute the same function.

Comment: ok thank you for the replies! But i have another question, is it possible to put those conditions all under one parentheses?

Comment: I would suggest you to refer the FAQ section before getting started with StackOverflow. It will help you out :)

Comment: Ok well thank you, you were all very helpful!!! ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be,

```
if ((a == 1 && b == 2) || (a == 2 && b == 3)) {
  //your function goes here
}
```

Here, we check if either of the two condition matches separating them with `||` which is nothing but an OR operator.

Just couple of suggestions here,

- If the data is `type` sensitive, make sure you use `===` which will check for the data type as well while comparing and not just the value
- You are using `var` keywords for each on of them else they'll be global.

Comment: Actually `if ((a == 1 && b == 2) || (a == 2 && b == 3))`.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. My program is a rock paper scissors game. What I mean is something like 

if (a == 1 && b == 2) || (a == 2 && b == 3) || (a == 3 && b == 1)

So that the condition can ONLY be met when ONLY the ands hold true. My program is a rock paper scissors game.

Comment: @DanD. aah, I missed the a == 2 part.. fixing. Thanks.

Comment: @idontknowanygoodusernames You should add that to your question instead of here in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((a == 1 && b == 2) || (a == 2 && b == 3)){
    executeFunction
}
```

Simply use parenthesis to group conditions, and check if one or more statements are true with the `OR operator` (`||`).

According to [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) the `AND operator` is executed before `OR operator`, so you can do the following without any difference:

```
if (a == 1 && b == 2 || a == 2 && b == 3){
    executeFunction
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you'r looking for [**JavaScript If...Else Statements**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp)

> **Conditional Statements**
>   Very often when you write code, you want to perform different actions for different decisions.
>
> You can use conditional statements in your code to do this.
>
> In JavaScript we have the following conditional statements:
>
> - Use if to specify a block of code to be executed, if a specified condition is true
> - Use else to specify a block of code to be executed, if the same condition is false
> - Use else if to specify a new condition to test, if the first condition is false
> - Use switch to specify many alternative blocks of code to be executed

and [JavaScript Logical Operators](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) :

```
 && and (x < 10 && y > 1) is true   
 || or  (x == 5 || y == 5) is false
 !  not !(x == y) is true
```

So using conditional statements you function would be like

```
if ((a == 1 || a == 2)&& (b == 2 || b == 3))
{
 executeFunction
}
```

Answer (score 0):

combine both conditions with or

```
If (a == 1 && b == 2 || a == 1 && b == 2)
{
    executeFunction;
}
```

Please note than the `&&` operation will be executed before the `||` operation. But for any general conditions you may use parentheses for every one like this.

```
If ((some conditions) || (some other conditions) || ...)
```

Or for your case

```
If ((a == 1 && b == 2) || (a == 1 && b == 2))
    do_someting();
```